# Can I compare Pearson's r and Spearman's rho with Fisher's r to z transformation?

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, spearman-rho, fisher-transform

I'm using the tool in the following website to compare correlation coefficients:
http://vassarstats.net/rdiff.html
The tool uses Fisher's r to z transformation to ultimately compare two correlation coefficients.

**Let's say I want to compare a correlation coefficient that was calculated with Pearson's correlation and a correlation coefficient that was calculated using Spearman's correlation. Is that ok to do? Or do both need to be calculated using the same correlation procedure (i.e., both Pearson's or both Spearman's?).**

Thanks.

Comment: In what situation would it make sense to compare a linear correlation with a correlation between ranks?

Comment: @Glen_b: Thanks. So I have two groups (group A and group B) and I want to compare correlations of the same two variables across groups. So let's say I want to compare the correlation between IQ and level of some biomarker across the groups. But let's say in group A I calculated Pearson's r while in group B I calculated Spearman's rho because in group B I failed to meet the assumptions to run Pearson's correlation. Continued in next comment...

Comment: I was thinking that since I'm using Fisher's r to z to normalize each correlation coefficient, then that should allow for comparisons regardless of which correlation method I used to calculate the two coefficients that I'm comparing. Are you saying that I can't do this? If so, then what are my options for comparing the correlations? Should I just run Spearman's for both?

Comment: Using $z$ on both is **assuming**that correlations $r$ on both methods are comparable, as it's the same transformation. It is not a way of **ensuring** that both are comparable. It is on all fours with having two Fahrenheit temperatures and converting them both to Celsius. By all means do that if it helps. A way forward is to realise that Spearman's method is, or should be, just Pearson's method applied to the ranks. The small print is how ranks are calculated when there are ties.

Comment: This is an example of the X-Y problem.  You should indeed care what kind of correlation between IQ and biomarker is more appropriate for the data, but looking  a scatter plot and knowing how variables are measured tells you immensely more than using a transformation. But on the big question, I don't think it makes much sense to compare a rank correlation on one group with a linear correlation on another.

Comment: @NickCox Many thanks for your reply. I get how informative simply looking at the scatterplots can be. But I will likely still choose to compare the correlation coefficients because I already did it for a previous analysis that my current analysis is connected to, and so I'm kind of committed. In that case, correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like you're saying that if I still end up deciding to go ahead with the comparisons of the correlation coefficients that the best way forward is to just use Spearman's for everything.

Comment: Sorry, no: I didn't say that and I can't say that because I have no idea what the data look like and I don't work in that science (although my bias is to doubt that there is any interesting correlation at all).  I don't follow that you are committed to anything here.  Another simpler take is that if Pearson and Spearman correlations are very different you probably need something different again, e.g. a transformation of one or both variables.

Comment: If you were actually interested in comparing linear correlations (you started with Pearson), a monotonic, non-linear correlation (Spearman) would not be how I'd do that. It might be a good idea to take one step further back still and carefully consider whether it's actually correlations you wish to compare, rather than something else. What's the underlying research question? If you do conclude that you wish to compare correlations, you need to be clear about whether it's linear or monotonic correlation that you want to compare. Then ask about a way to achieve that aim.

Comment: @Glen_b: I want to look at the association between certain biomarkers and different types of IQ in two different groups of people to see firstly if levels of the biomarkers are linked with IQ within each group, and then also make comparisons between the two groups. I simplified my problem a bit. There are multiple types of IQ (e.g., math IQ, verbal IQ, general IQ, etc) and multiple types of biomarkers (biomarker 1, biomarker 2, biomarker 3, etc). And I'm measuring correlations between each possible combination of IQ types and biomarkers. Continued in next comment...

Comment: In certain cases I decided that Spearman's would be more appropriate than Pearson's because either one or both of the variables are non-normal and/or have outliers and/or I think that the relationship between the two variables will likely be monotonic (instead of linear) based on past literature. I realize multiple regression would probably be a better approach for this... but it's for a class project and I need to use correlations for reasons too long to explain...

Comment: Abandoning Pearson due to non-normality is not necessary (and especially not only to one side of the comparison). If you do want to pick up monotonic relationships, then Spearman should generally be okay.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks!

Comment: That said, it doesn't imply that you can *always* use the usual tests of Pearson correlation. Sometimes you can stick to Pearson but need to modify the test. Doesn't affect you if you're using Spearman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two coefficients don't measure the same thing, so your comparison will be more appropriate if you use the same correlation in both cases. If you're worried about model assumptions, use Spearman. However keep in mind that model assumptions are always idealisations, so it is wrong to say that for example you can only use Pearson correlation if data are normal. Even if you want a formal comparison, I'd look at plots first to see whether there is anything that makes the Pearson correlation really misleading at least in one of your cases, such as domination by an outlier.

Note also that the tool you cite is about significance testing and will give you a misleading comparison at least if sample sizes are different. Also it doesn't solve the problem that not the same thing is measured by the two correlations.

Comment: I'd say the main use of the z transformation was getting confidence intervals, although significance tests clearly could be linked.